# How to send Azure monitor metric alerts to Slack

Tags: azure, webhooks, azure-rm-template, azure-monitoring

I have been trying to add an Azure monitor alert to slack. The resource is being provisioned via ARM template. However I couldn't get the alert to go to slack.

This is my `actions` section in the template

```
   "actions": [
      {
        "actionGroupId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/actionGroups/', 'SlackWebhook')]",
        "webHookProperties": {
          "text": "Alert: memory usage exceeded threshold"
        }
      }
    ]
```

I have set up a dummy webhook to inspect the payload being sent. This is what I found

```
{
  "schemaId": "AzureMonitorMetricAlert",
  "data": {
    "version": "2.0",
    "properties": {
      "text": "Dropbox connector Memory usage exceeded the threshold of 1GB"
    },
    "status": "Activated",
    "context": {...}
  }
}
```

The property goes inside `data.properties`. Slack expects the `text` property to be at the top level of request body. How to make this work?

Comment: you have a `workbooks` (a visualization tool) tag on here, do you mean `webhooks`? i think you do :)

Comment: @JohnGardner You are correct!